# Making a program timer-based rather than frame-rate dependent?

Tags: c++, directx

I have a game engine to work on as part of a class. Currently, its rendering is frame-rate dependent and one requirement is to move to a timer-based dependency.  I am not sure how to determine where it is relying on frame-rates.  I'm not sure what to look for.  I realize I'm going to need to somehow incorporate a timer (GetTickCount?) to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how frequent to update that, either.

I'm not looking to be handed code, just some helpful guidelines possibly?

Comment: Well, you are limited by your frame rate, no?  For example, you cannot continuously update input if your frame rate is lagging behind.

Comment: That's a logical assumption.  However, as it stands it's very stop and go with the speed of the computer fluctuating.  I assume I'm being requested to keep this at some kind of steady, timer based state, rather than just updating and rendering at random intervals?  I'm really not entirely understanding, thus the question :)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you have a very simple game, where it's just a ball moving across the screen. Without time-based updates, it moves as fast as you update.

What you want to do is find out how much time has elapsed (in a fraction. I usually measure in seconds, so physics equations match better.) When updating, instead of something like this:

```
ballPosition += ballVelocity
```

You'd have this:

```
ballPosition += ballVelocity * timeElapsed
```

What this means is that for higher frame rates, `timeElapsed` will be lower, which consequently moves the ball less. Lower frame rates means that `timeElapsed` will be greater, and the ball will move more per-frame.

In the end, the ball will move the same distance independent on frame rate. A 60 FPS update rate makes `timeElapsed` equal `0.01666667f`, while a 30 FPS update rate would make it `0.03333333f` . You can see how at 60 FPS, the elapsed time is half of 30 FPS, but because it's twice as fast, it's the same number.

I usually pass `timeElapsed` as an argument to any functions that are time-dependent. A nice consequence of doing it this way is you can slow down or speed up your game by multiplying the elapsed time by a value. You can also apply that to individual components. It also plays well if you switch to a frame-limiting model instead, because you're effectively just forcing `timeElapsed` to be a constant. Pseudo-code:

```
while (gameRunning)
{
    const float timeElapsed =
                    timer.elapsed(); // elapsed returns the number of seconds
                                     // passed since it was last called

    // GlobalTimeScale is 1 for normal time
    game.update(timeElapsed * GlobalTimeScale);
    game.draw();
}
```

To get the time, [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx) should work. You might also take a look at [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) for higher precision, though it can have issues with multiple cores.

Comment: The problem with this scheme is that you are setting the time elapsed for th next frame based on the speed of the previous frame.  Quite often this will introduce a nasty stuttering  effect due to the way drivers buffer multiple frames worth of data.  If you are going to do it this way it is best to average over several frames.  This will eliminate a lot of these stuttering issues.

Comment: @Goz: are you speaking of some kind of floating average 0.50 * last + 0.30 * beforeLast + 0.20 beforeBeforeLast ? ie giving more weight to recent times to adapt more quickly to change.

Comment: You can do it weighted.  Personally I've found that even at pretty low frame rates (15fps) averaging the last 3 frame rates gives you plenty good enough results as to be unnoticeable :)

Comment: As always, experiment and see what gives you the best result :)

Comment: Indeed, I've had good results averaging the last 5 frame times together.

Comment: deques work pretty good for keeping rate information of past frames. They are usually implemented as a circular buffer, and are pretty fast.  Just pop off the end and throw it away, then add the new framerate on the front, average and violla.

Comment: Or even just using `boost::circular_buffer.`

Answer (score 1):

I used [fix your timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) with some success

The issue then becomes keeping track of any lag... and slowing the thing down if the computer can't keep up.

Answer (score 0):

A possible pseudocode game loop:

```
constant TIMETHRESHOLD xxxx // nanoseconds to pass between executions of game loop

while true loop
    if getTime() - previousTime > TIMETHRESHOLD
        previousTime = getTime();
        // Execute game logic here
    end if
end loop
```

The thing is that you can have different TIMETHRESHOLD for different parts of the game logic. For example you could like the frame rate to be 60fps but if the physics engine "works" at 30fps is enough... this kind of things. With a fast hardware it will work as intended, and with slower hardware (one that can not meet the time requirements) it will work as fast as it can anyways. Of course this is a simple, mono-process example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure where the frame-rates are being used, it's almost certainly implicit in your main loop. If you have a call to a rendering function in your main loop, and rendering takes a long time, then the "loop rate" of your main loop is the same as your frame rate, right? Single threaded execution means *everything that is processed in the loop* contributes to your frame rate.